# How to set total playtime of file in Chronometer meter in android

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, chronometer

Hello everyone  in facing a problem in setting the total playtime of a mp3 media file in Chronometer.

Please help me how i can set it .

im getting the time from media player like :

**mediaPlayer.getDuration() return audio play time in milliseconds.
for eg: if file total playtime is 3 min  then time in milliseconds =180000**

```
File file = new File(dir, "media.mp3");

                if(file.exists()){

                    mChronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    play_and_stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try {

                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());

                        mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -mediaPlayer.getDuration());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

and below is my Chronometer meter class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Chronometer extends TextView {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "Chronometer";

    public interface OnChronometerTickListener {

        void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer);
    }

    private long mBase;
    private boolean mVisible;
    private boolean mStarted;
    private boolean mRunning;
    private OnChronometerTickListener mOnChronometerTickListener;

    private static final int TICK_WHAT = 2;

    private long timeElapsed;

    public Chronometer(Context context) {
        this (context, null, 0);
    }

    public Chronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this (context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Chronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super (context, attrs, defStyle);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mBase = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        updateText(mBase);
    }

    public void setBase(long base) {
        mBase = base;
        dispatchChronometerTick();
        updateText(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    }

    public long getBase() {
        return mBase;
    }

    public void setOnChronometerTickListener(
            OnChronometerTickListener listener) {
        mOnChronometerTickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnChronometerTickListener getOnChronometerTickListener() {
        return mOnChronometerTickListener;
    }

    public void start() {
        mStarted = true;
        updateRunning();
    }

    public void stop() {
        mStarted = false;
        updateRunning();
    }


    public void setStarted(boolean started) {
        mStarted = started;
        updateRunning();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super .onDetachedFromWindow();
        mVisible = false;
        updateRunning();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
        super .onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
        mVisible = visibility == VISIBLE;
        updateRunning();
    }

    private synchronized void updateText(long now) {

        timeElapsed = now - mBase;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");

        int hours = (int)(timeElapsed / (3600 * 1000));
        int remaining = (int)(timeElapsed % (3600 * 1000));

        int minutes = (int)(remaining / (60 * 1000));
        remaining = (int)(remaining % (60 * 1000));

        int seconds = (int)(remaining / 1000);
        remaining = (int)(remaining % (1000));

        int milliseconds = (int)(((int)timeElapsed % 1000) / 100);

        String text = "";

        if (hours > 0) {
            text += df.format(hours) + ":";
        }

        text += df.format(hours) + ":";
        text += df.format(minutes) + ":";
        text += df.format(seconds);
        //text += df.format(Integer.toString(milliseconds));
        setText(text);
    }

    private void updateRunning() {
        boolean running = mVisible && mStarted;
        if (running != mRunning) {
            if (running) {
                updateText(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                dispatchChronometerTick();
                mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(mHandler,
                        TICK_WHAT), 100);
            } else {
                mHandler.removeMessages(TICK_WHAT);
            }
            mRunning = running;
        }
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message m) {
            if (mRunning) {
                updateText(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                dispatchChronometerTick();
                sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(this , TICK_WHAT),
                        100);
            }
        }
    };

    void dispatchChronometerTick() {
        if (mOnChronometerTickListener != null) {
            mOnChronometerTickListener.onChronometerTick(this);
        }
    }

    public long getTimeElapsed() {
        return timeElapsed;
    }

}
```